# Как на python организовать сравнение двух строк?

Tags: python

Пробовал проходить по строкам циклом и увеличивать переменную coincidences при совпадении

```
s = "hello world how are you doing"
a = "doing"
coincidences = 0
for r in range(max(len(a), len(s))):
    try:
        if s[r] == a[r]:
            coincidences += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
print(100/max(len(s), len(a)) * coincidences)
```

Но не хватает точности сравнения.

Есть ли модуль для сравнения строк в python?

Comment: Вообще, зависит от того, что вы имеете в виду под точностью. Есть модуль [strsimpy](https://pypi.org/project/strsimpy/) для сравнения строк, в том числе там например реализованы разные вариации [расстояния Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). Также см. модуль [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)

Comment: Может хватит точности от библиотеки difflib <https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю можно попробовать что такого вида, если вы хотите проверять на сколько процентов одна строка входит в другую

```py
s = "hello world how are you doing"
a = "doing"
mn_string, mx_string = (s, a) if len(s) < len(a) else (a, s)

for i in range(len(mn_string)-1, -1, -1):
  if mn_string[:i+1] in mx_string:
    coincidences = i+1
    break

print(coincidences*100/ len(mx_string)) # 17.24137931034483
```

но это не будет работать в случае если обе строки будут содержать по несколько слов и важно что слова могут стоять на разных местах
например:

```
# тут сработает верно, ответ около 48 
s = "My name is Dima"
a = "is Dima"

# тут сработает неверно, ответ будет 0
s = "My name is Dima"
a = "They call me Dima"
```